# Java - how to add dot character like in a HTML unordered list

Tags: java, unicode-string

Is there a possibility to parse String in Java in such a way that there is a dot char like:

- List item
- List item

I'd like to have unordered list in my String to generate email from this String.

My String look like

```
private static final String ACCEPT_AUTH_APPLICATION_MSG = "lorem ipsum " +
            "lorem ipsum.\n\n" +
            "lorem ipsum:\n"(below my unordered list with dots)
```

Thank you in advice!
Matthew

Comment: Try using the unicode character `\u2022`
Something like `\u2022 List item`

Comment: Or you could send an email with a HTML body.

Comment: The ultimate safe way to do it is with a `*`

Answer (score 2):

As @Dom said in the comment, it is good enough to use the unicode encoding for the bullet character.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\u2022 List item");
    }

}
```

Output is exactly:

```
• List item
```